# React AntD Select style scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scrollbar, antd

I am trying to access the scrollbar styling in the antD Select component. I have found where to style the scrollbar but it is not functional. Meaning, it shows up when I remove the `diplay: none` from the style and change the color, but it doesn't scroll. Am I doing something wrong. In order to change the style I am doing something like this...
[image]

[image]

Also, I found a way to add a functional scrollbar using this code...

```
.ant-select-dropdown{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[image]

But this does not allow me to style the dropdown scrollbar. Instead I have to style it using the webkit which styles this everywhere and I cannot get it to fit exactly in the dropwdown. I was hoping to use the antD one, as it looks nicer, but it doesn't function for some reason. Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here by setting this on the select element.
[image]